# Pig: positionals counting from right?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a tuple in my pig script:

```
((,v1,fb,fql))
```

I know I can choose elements from the left as $0 (blank), $1 ("v1"), etc. But can I choose elements from the right? The tuples will be different lengths, but I would always like to get the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can however write a python UDF to extract it:

```
# Make sure to include the appropriate ouputSchema
def getFromBack(TUPLE, pos):
    # gets elements from the back of TUPLE 
    # You can also do TUPLE[-pos], but this way it starts at 0 which is closer
    # to Pig
    return TUPLE[::-1][pos]

    # This works the same way as above, but may be faster
    # return TUPLE[-(pos + 1)]
```

And used like:

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as pythonUDFs ;

B = FOREACH A GENERATE pythonUDFs.getFromBack(T, 0) ;
```